# complex mysql query need result sorted

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 mysql tables. I want to display leaderboard for team in descending order of d_money for particular day (like day 1, day 2, day 3.)

```
user(u_id(p),name)
team(t_id(p),u_id(f),t_name,t_money,days_money) and 
history(t_id(f),day,d_money).
```

First i collected all `t_id`'s in `$tid_arr`. Then for each `t_id`, i wrote query to get `t_name` and its days money.(for particular day. Here - day 1). It displays the result. But i want the result sorted (descending order of `d_money`). But i couldn't find the soultion.

```
 $query = $con->prepare("SELECT t_id FROM team");   
$query->execute();

$tid_arr = $query->fetchAll();



 echo "<table border='1'>";

foreach($tid_arr as $tid)
 {
    $que = $con->prepare("SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team, history WHERE history.t_id=$tid['t_id'] AND team.t_id=history.t_id` AND history.day='1'");
                     $que->execute();


                               while($info = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
                              {

                                     echo "<tr>";
                                     echo  "<td>".$info[0]."</td>";
                                     echo  "<td>".$info[1]."</td>";
                                     echo "</tr>";
              }
}
                echo "</table>";
```

Comment: just add `ORDER BY d_money DESC` at the end of query.

Comment: it wouldn't work, i'm adding rows one by one for each query.

Comment: I see what you mean. Clarification needed: First order by `d_money`, then `t_id` or the reverse? The first query may not be necessary if you combine two queries into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order by `d_money` then `t_id`, you can use the following query. The 1st query is unnecessary and should be removed.

```
SELECT d_money, t_name FROM team a 
LEFT JOIN history b ON a.t_id=b.t_id
WHERE history.day='1' 
ORDER BY d_money DESC, t_id DESC
```

p.s. `user` table is not used ?

Comment: yeah, shouldn't have added 'user' table.

Comment: It works, that's very simple i think. I was making it difficult enough to confuse me. haha..Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Join and Order By clause to your SQL statement to be

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
$que = $con->prepare("SELECT T.t_id, H.d_money, T.t_name
                  FROM team T INNER JOIN history H ON T.t_id=H.t_id
                  WHERE H.day='1'
                  ORDER BY d_money DESC");
$que->execute();

while ($info = $que->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo  "<td>".$info[0]."</td>";
 echo  "<td>".$info[1]."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: It should work after we removed the first SELECT and add JOIN